# offset texture attached to frameBuffer to render panorama

Tags: opengl, terrain-rendering, frame-buffer

I would like to pre-render horizon of large landscape to texture and than paste it as cylindrical screen around the camera (to accelerate rendering of distant details)

Easiest would be make 8-gon screen uv-mapped to 4096x512 pixel frambuffer texture and render from 8 angles of camera with frustum 360/8=45 degrees wide (each angle mapped to different tile of framebuffer texture).

like this
[image]

But as far as I know output framebuffer texture is always mapped to whole framebuffer i.e. to whole camera frustrum. Is that right? Is there a way how to choose mapping for frambuffer output texture?

Comment: Are you using a particular engine or framework? The exact details will vary from case to case, but most will expose some concept of a "viewport" that you can configure to be a smaller rectangle within your output buffer.

Comment: aha sorry, I forgot to specidy OpenGL (3+)